# Android: create round layout with colored header

Tags: android, background, background-color

I want to create a layout like in [image: the picture] but I don't know why, it does not work anymore. I can't see the color of the header

here the drawable of the parent: mission_detail_background.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="#25000000" />
<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="8dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="8dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="8dp"
    android:topRightRadius="8dp" />
</shape>
```

and the xml of the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<data>
    <variable
        name="missionDetailViewModel"
        type="com.youstock.mover.viewmodel.MissionDetailViewModel" />
</data>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/missionDetail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        **android:background="@drawable/mission_detail_background"**
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/warehouse_layout">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/detail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            **android:backgroundTint="@color/colorMissionDetail"**
            android:padding="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvMission"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/mission"
                android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tvDetail"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvDetail"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/detail"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvMission" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvInfo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:text="@{missionDetailViewModel.missionDetailLiveData.detail}"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/detail" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

If I change the backgroundTint by background, I see the color but borders are covered

Where does the problem come from?
Thanks for your help

Comment: Borders will cover because the layout starts from the start of the parent so it will cover the border, also the top rounded corners will cover because the inside layout is not top rounded.
You have to create new drawable for the inner layout with top rounded corners.

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<data>
    <variable
        name="missionDetailViewModel"
        type="com.youstock.mover.viewmodel.MissionDetailViewModel" />
</data>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    android:id="@+id/missionDetail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:background="@drawable/mission_detail_background"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/warehouse_layout">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/detail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/back_grey"
        android:padding="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvMission"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/mission"
            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tvDetail"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvDetail"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/detail"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvMission" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvInfo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:text="@{missionDetailViewModel.missionDetailLiveData.detail}"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/detail" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</layout>
```

back_grey.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners
        android:topLeftRadius="8dp"
        android:topRightRadius="8dp" />
    <solid android:color="#C8C8C8"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: Thanks, I've already think about that. It work in this case, but I have anothers where the rount have to be on each corner. I think the only solution is programmatically